# what is the purpose of the [] that follow after auto keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Hi I came across this example

```
 auto [ptr, ec] { std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result) };
```

Can someone please explain the what is the syntax autp [ptr,ec] {} , this is something I am seeing for the first time. Is this new in C++ ?

Any link to the documentation will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's called structured binding. Available since C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding.

Comment: It is looking like definition of lambda function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
Captures prt and ec variables and run code specified in { }

Comment: @MihanEntalpo No, it's structured binding. It's lambda syntax only if it doesn't start with the `auto` keyword.

Comment: `std::pair<int, int> f(); auto p = f();` would be the classic way, `p` being the pair returned. Now with structured binding you could automatically unpack the pair as `auto [f, s] = f();` with `f` and `s` holding the `int`s of the pair's first and second member – note that I used assignment syntax here, which is equivalent, but makes (in my eyes) the code more obvious...

Comment: Ok, I see no semicolon in braces, so it couldn't be a lambda.

Comment: Hm... This drives me to add two rules for my personal coding conventions: 1. For structured bindings assignment syntax (see my comment above) gets *mandatory*. 2. For lambdas the optional `()` for empty argument list gets mandatory as well (i.e. `auto f = [](){ /*... */}`. -> Above pseudo-ambiguities (admitted, just requires a closer look...) solved.