# What does auto [var1, var2] = func() mean?

Tags: c++, lambda

I don't know how to better phrase my question, since it's the first time encountering this. Basically I have a function and inside this function an anonymous function is called(a lambda).

```
std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os){
/*
    some code
*/
    classMember.doSmth([&](std::size_t num){
           auto [var1, var2] = classMember.funcThatReturnsATupple(num) // <- this I don't understand
    });
}

void doSmth(const std::function<void(std::size_t num)>& function) const{
    //does stuff
}
```

`var1` and `var2` are not declared anywhere in `Print()`. I'm only allowed to declare them in `doSmth()`, but i don't quite understand what they are, nor how they work. Is the following somewhat equivalent to `auto [var1, var2] = classMember.funcThatReturnsATupple(num)`?

```
auto var1 = classMember.funcThatReturnsATupple(num); 
auto var2 = classMember.funcThatReturnsATupple(num);
```

`auto [var1, var2]` calls a function which return a tuple, which has two elements(`std::tuple<int, int>`). Does the fist value of the tuple get stored in `var1` and the second one in `var2`? I get the error that `var1` and `var2` are not declared. Do I need to declare them in `doSmth()`?

Comment: Its structure binding. See also [what is the purpose of the [ \] that follow after auto keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726812/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-that-follow-after-auto-keyword)